# What does 'touch' stand for?

Tags: history, touch

My question is not so much a question of computer science as it is a question of etymology.

The command `touch` changes file access and modification times.

**What does 'touch' stand for?**

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It doesn't *stand for* anything; it's not an abbreviation or initialism.  It's a verb.

When you `touch` a file, you're "putting fresh fingerprints on it", updating its last-modified date (or creating it if it did not yet exist).

Comment: Oohh. It was not intuitive to me that the verb 'touch' would be a good match for the role of the command `touch` but I get it now. Thanks

Comment: Short explanation, to the point and explaining exactly what it does. However it is generally used to create a file.

Comment: It's certainly _frequently_ used for that, but its own self-description on its own `man` page is: "`touch -- change file access and modification times`".

Comment: I suppose one could ask "when was the file last touched?" to mean when it was last changed (e.g. by writing to it), or "the file hasn't been touched in years". The `touch` command simulates the effect, hence the name.

Answer (score 3):

As DopeGhoti says, updating the timestamps to the current time fits well with the semantic meaning of the English word.  It's common to talk about "touching" data in memory to mean accessing it (e.g. "this function touches 2GB of data, so it trashes the CPU's caches").  The `touch(1)` command exists to touch a file in a way that produces an effect on the metadata, without other effects.

It also has options to set the time/date metadata to something other than the current time, in which case the semantic meaning doesn't really apply anymore.  (e.g. `touch -r reference_file /tmp/foo` to set mtime and atime to be the same as the reference).

---

Somewhat related:

In case you were curious, the GNU coreutils `touch(1)` implementation uses this sequence of system calls to update timestamps to the current time:

```
$ strace touch /tmp/foo
...
open("/tmp/foo", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_NOCTTY|O_NONBLOCK, 0666) = 3
dup2(3, 0)                              = 0
close(3)                                = 0
```

`open` with `O_CREAT` achieves the create-if-missing behaviour.  Omitting `O_TRUNC` preserves the existing contents, like `>> /tmp/foo` would.  `dup2` updates the all three of mtime, atime, and ctime to the current time.  (Just the `open()`/`close()` alone don't affect the timestamps).

To set the time to something other than "now", it does the same sequence, then uses [`utimensat(0, NULL, ...)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/utimensat.2.html) to set the times on the file referred to by stdout (since it duplicated the fd for that file to fd0).